# UIButton on top of view with userInteractionEnabled=NO

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm creating a transparent layer on top of `keyWindow`

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
_topLayer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:window.frame];
_topLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_topLayer.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[window addSubview:_topLayer];
```

I'm adding subview that I want to appear on top of everything. I used

```
userInteractionEnabled = NO
```

so that layer is not blocking taps to the underneath staff.

I was trying to add a UIButton on top of that layer, but it is not responding to taps, due to the above `userInteractionEnabled = NO`

How can I allow the button to be responsive, while leaving the full background as transparent?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try to use 'bringSubViewToFront' method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this: `subclass` the `UIView` with `userInteractionEnabled=YES` then use this snippet:

```
-(id)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    id hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView == self) return nil; // <--- pass-through if touch on UIView
    else return hitView; // touch on children
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @anhtu is a real complication to what I was trying to achieve. The correct way is to set the button as a sibling of of the transparent view, instead of adding it as a child view.

See an expansion of this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35592676/913347