# Is it possible to dim a UIView but allow touch of elements behind it?

Tags: ios, uikit

How would you have a grey overlay on top, but allow to touch buttons beneath it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `userInteraction` of overlay to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can set `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`.

**But pay attention:** when you create a full screen transparent view, and set its `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`, **all the subviews of that view will not be responsive to user actions**. If you add a button on your view, it will not respond to user taps! and another problem: if you set the `alpha` value of that view to be transparent, e.g. `0.4`, then all its subviews will be transparent too!

The solution is simple: don't put any subview on your transparent view, but instead, add your other elements as siblings of your view. Here is Objective-C code to show what I mean: (notice the comments which say it all):

```
//Create a full screen transparent view:
UIView *vw = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
vw.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
vw.alpha = 0.4;
vw.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

//Create a button to appear on top of the transparent view:
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 80, 44)];
btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[btn setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setTitle:@"Pressed" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
//(*) Bad idea: [vw addSubview:btn];

//(**) Correct way to have the button respond to user interaction:
//    Add it as a sibling of the full screen view
[self.view addSubview:vw];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Comment: Or to put it simply:  First, create all the buttons etc. in the parent view. Get those to work. THEN add the overlay view to the parent. Doing in this order, it is clear that nothing is being added as a child of the overlay. It is just another child, which happens to visually overlap others.